# Simple php login for static Godaddy website

Tags: php, html, mysql, authentication

I am building a website using html, css and javascript. It's a Godaddy domain and also hosted there. The company I'm working for does not want the site to be accessible by anyone until they are ready to launch. I need to create a very simple php login (just 1 user) where my colleagues can enter the credentials to view the progress of the site in production. I have no experience with php and minimal mysql experience. How would I go about creating such an authentication?

Comment: Do you even need login at this point then. Why not just put the files in a hard to guess foldername. Security by obscurity might be good enough?

Comment: auth basic would be easy to add http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of adding login feature you can restrict it using `.htaccess`.

Here is the link which can help to password protect the site using `.htaccess`

http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/password-protection/